# Awk for merging multiple files with common column

Tags: awk, merge, table

I have a question concerning awk command in unix to merge multiple tables with a common value

Tab1

```
Geneid  Chr Start   End Strand  Length Sample_1
ENSG00000278267 1   17369   17436   -   68  0
ENSG00000243485 1;1;1   29554;30267;30976   30039;30667;31109   +;+;+   1021    0
```

Tab 2

```
Geneid  Chr Start   End Strand  Length Sample_2
ENSG00000278267 1   17369   17436   -   68  0
ENSG00000243485 1;1;1   29554;30267;30976   30039;30667;31109   +;+;+   1021    0
```

Tab 3

```
Geneid  Chr Start   End Strand  Length Sample_3
ENSG00000278267 1   17369   17436   -   68  0
ENSG00000243485 1;1;1   29554;30267;30976   30039;30667;31109   +;+;+   1021    0
```

As you can see, Geneid is similar in these tables, and I would like to merge these files into 1 with the GeneID column and the "Sample_n" column

```
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1] = $7; next} {print $1,$7,h[$1]}' Sample_1.txt Sample_2.txt | head
```

If I don't miss something it means:
NR==FNR, the first file is the template for the output
{h[$1] = $7; next} h contains the GeneID of file 1 associated with value in 7th column
{print $1,$7,h[$1]} print the first/seven/ column of the second file for the GeneID contained in h value

This work for 2 files, but not for 3 or more

```
Geneid Sample_1 Sample_2
ENSG00000278267 0 0 
ENSG00000243485 0 0
```

I looked on this website, and people posted all the code, but I don't really understand the command, so does anybody know how to merge these files and can explain parameters in the command ?

Comment: Welcome to U/L. I haven't tried the awk code, but a simpler way is to just use `join`.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but as I had a lot of file, I looked on awk command. @glen jackman  comment solved it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '
    {samples[$1] = samples[$1] OFS $NF} 
    END {
        # print the header first
        print "Geneid", samples["Geneid"] 
        delete samples["Geneid"]
        # and then the rest of the data
        for (geneid in samples) print geneid, samples[geneid]
    }
' Tab*
```

Pipe the output into `| column -t` if you want to line up the columns

Comment: Thanks a lot for the codes and explanations, It works fine :D